# Switching between browsers in protractor

Tags: browser, protractor, chat, between, switching

I m doing automation Testing of an angular 4 chat application using protractor in that i m doing login of two diffrent users in chrome and firefox browser respectively. Now after login they there is a button of chat. On click on chat button one new window of each browser will open. Now for chat i have to do continuous switching between these 2 window. How can i do that? I provided chrome as a browser in protractor configuration file and to open firefox browser i am using following snippet.

let driver_fx;
driver_fx = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using 2 configuration files and run them one after another. 
For example I run conf1.js (run on chrome) to run test1.js and then run conf2.js (run on firefox) to run test2.js and validate received message.

Comment: that's not the correct way i guess. I want to run with only command as protractor conf.js